# ClickHouse.MaterializedPostgreSQL engine. Use custom domain

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, clickhouse

I add data replication to ClickHouse with help of MaterializedPostgreSQL from PostgreSQL. In my schema, in PostgreSQL i have custom domain like:

> CREATE DOMAIN domain_name AS NUMERIC(24, 10)
> CONSTRAINT "value_should_not_be_a_negative" CHECK (VALUE >= 0);

When data replicate to ClickHouse from PostgreSQL, in ClickHouse i have

```
    SHOW CREATE TABLE db_name.table_name

Query id: some_id

┌─statement──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ CREATE TABLE db_name.table_name
(
    `id` UUID,
    `idx` Int32,
    `some_field_which_should_be_as_domain_type` String,
    ---------------------------------------------↑
    `_sign` Int8() MATERIALIZED 1,
    `_version` UInt64() MATERIALIZED 1
)
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree(_version)
ORDER BY (id, idx) │
```

in field some_field_which_should_be_as_domain_type i expected type like domain_name (NUMERIC data type) but i got string. Is it possible to configurate supporting custom domain when i replicate data from PostgreSQL to ClickHouse?

Comment: it looks like unfinished code for data type conversion, on clickhouse-server side
try to upgrade to 23.7 version and if reproduce create issue on https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/